# Bootstrap 4 - Hamburger Menu Does Not Appear On Mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an app using Bootstrap 4. At the moment, I'm working to target this app on desktops and mobile phones. I want the

**Desktop**

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| This is the title of my app                   [button] |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                        |
|                                                        |
|                                                        |
|                                                        |
|                                                        |
|                                                        |
|                                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Mobile**

```
+-----------------------+
| This is|          [=] |
+--------|              |
|        |     [button] |
|        |              |
|        |              |
|        |              |
|        |              |
|        |              |
|        |              |
+--------+--------------+
```

I have a Bootply [here](https://www.bootply.com/ZpjkZEThBv), with the following code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Some Really Long Title Goes Here</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>        

    <div id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn btn-outline-warning" href="#" target="_blank">Action Button</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>                
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <p>Here are the details of the page</p>
</div>
```

For some reason though, the hamburger menu appears in full-screen mode. Which I don't want. At the same time, when I select the hamburger menu, no options appear. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve your issue.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Some Really Long Title Goes Here</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>        

    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn btn-outline-warning" href="#" target="_blank">Action Button</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>                
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <p>Here are the details of the page</p>
</div>
```

The code was missing navbar-expand-md in the nav element and "collapse navbar-collapse" in the drop down area.

Hope this helps.